# How can I get the two subsets (SA,SB) given two sets (A,B) and a list L of pairs (a,b) s.t. the Cartesian product of SA and SB is in L?

Tags: python, algorithm, set

I have two list A and B that represent the two sets:

`A = [1,2,3,4,5]`

`B = [a,b,c,d,e,f]`

And a list L containing some pairs (a,b) with a belonging to A and b belonging to B. Note that L do not contain all the possible combinations.

`L = [(1,a),(1,f),(2,d),(3,a),(3,f),(4,b),(5,f)]`

I need to find SA and SB such that SA x SB (Cartesian Product) is in L, maximizing |SA| * |SB|
In the example

`SA = [1,3]`
`SB = [a,f]`

Comment: I think this is not a polynomial problem and it can be reduced to NP-Complete problem: finding maximum complete subgraph in a bipartite graph. Some solutions are discussed here: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/49878/bipartite-graph-how-to-determine-largest-subsets-that-are-all-connected

Comment: SA x SB have to be in L

Comment: What is the maximum number of elements that can be in A, B and L?

Comment: They are not known

Answer (score 0):

i think it'll cost O(n!)

```
from collections import defaultdict as dd
import itertools as it

a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
b = ["a", "b", "c", "d"]

p = [i for i in it.product(a,b)]
p.remove(p[5])
p.remove(p[2])
p.remove(p[8])
#till here we create a list of tuples

dict_key_x = dd(set) #dict with x values as key and all y values in set as value
for tup in p:
    dict_key_x[tup[0]].add(tup[1])

max_len = 0
max_value = [-1,-1]

comb_x = [] #a list with all combination of all length from x values
for i in range(1,len(dict_key_x)+1):
    for j in it.combinations(dict_key_x.keys(),i):
        comb_x.append(j)

for comb in comb_x: #for every combination check the Intersection of the y values of all x
    mutual = dict_key_x[comb[0]]
    for x_value in comb:
        mutual = mutual & dict_key_x[x_value]
    if len(comb)*len(mutual)>max_len:
         max_len = len(comb)+len(mutual)
         max_value[0]=comb
         max_value[1] = mutual
print(max_value)
print(max_len)
print(p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use combinations (from itertools) to produce subsets of A and, for each of them determine the common elements of B that are found through L which you can index as a dictionary.  This will give you pairs of subsets that have a non-empty product.  Using the max() function, you can find the pair with the largest product.

```
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools   import combinations

def findProdSets(A,B,L):
    d = defaultdict(set)
    for a,b in L: d[a].add(b)
    for size in range(1,len(A)+1):
        for subsetA in combinations(A,size):
            subsetB = set.intersection(*(d[a] for a in subsetA))
            if len(subsetB)>0:
                yield subsetA,tuple(subsetB)

A = [1,2,3,4,5]
B = ["a","b","c","d","e","f"]
L = [(1,"a"),(1,"f"),(2,"d"),(3,"a"),(3,"f"),(4,"b"),(5,"f")]

subSetA,subSetB = max(findProdSets(A,B,L),key=lambda c:len(c[0])*len(c[1]))
print(subSetA,subSetB)               

(1, 3) ('a', 'f')
```

*To optimize this, you could modify the findProdSets function so that it returns the pair of sets with the largest product.  This would allow it to exit early by starting with the largest size and stopping then `size x len(A)` is less or equal to the largest product found so far*